# Jquery форма отправляет письма даже при ошибке

Tags: jquery

Сам скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#valid').text('');
        $('#valid2').text(' ');
        $('#valid3').text(' ');
        $('#valid4').text(' ');

        $('#email').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.?([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([[a-z0-9-]+\.)[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
                if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                     $('#valid2').text(' ');
                      } else {
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                    $('#valid2').text('Enter a valid email address to send to');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                $('#valid2').text('You forgot to enter the email address to send to');
            }
        });

        $('#name').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                var pattern = /^.{1,40}$/i;
                if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});
                    $('#valid').text(' ');
                } else {
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                    $('#valid').text('Please enter a value less than or equal to 40');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                $('#valid').text('You forgot to enter the your name to send to');
            }
        });
           $('#subject').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                var pattern = /^.{1,100}$/i;
                if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});

                } else {
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                    $('#valid3').text('Please enter a value less than or equal to 100');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                $('#valid3').text('You forgot to enter the subject to send to');
            }
        });
           $('#message').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') {
                var pattern = /^.{1,4096}$/i;
                if(pattern.test($(this).val())){
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #569b44'});

                } else {
                    $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                    $('#valid4').text('Please enter a value less than or equal to 4096');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({'border' : '1px solid #ff0000'});
                $('#valid4').text('You forgot to enter the message to send to');
            }
        });

           });

    </script>
```

вот форма

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" >
               <div class="span-25 last" style="height: 60px;">
               <div class="span-8 form notopmargin">
                  <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required /><span id="valid"></span><br />
                </div>
                <div class="span-8 form last notopmargin">
                  <input class="text" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" required /><span id="valid2"></span><br />
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span-17 last notopmargin">
                    <input class="texts" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" required /><span id="valid3"></span><br />
                </div>
                <div class="span-17 last">
                    <textarea class="text" name="message" id="message" value="" rows="5" cols="25" placeholder="Message" required ></textarea><span id="valid4"></span><br />
                </div>
                <div class="span-12 notopmargin">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" id="submit_form" required/>
                </div>

                </form>
```

Как мне заставить не отправлять письмо и вытаскивать окно с предупреждением об ошибке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логика валидации формы должна быть примерно следующая:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    if ($('input.class1').val() == '') {
        alert('Error');
        return false;
    } else if ($('input.class2').val() == '') {
        alert('Error');
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).submit();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В тег form нужно добавить обработчик onsubmit="validate()".

Функция validate будет определять наличие ошибок и если таковые есть то нужно возвращать false, тогда отправка происходить не будет.

Следить за наличием ошибок можно через глобальную переменную, которая будет флагом "есть ошибки/нет ошибок".

Comment: Спасибо конечно за ответ и думаю он правильный) но можно ли капнуть глубже?
добавил скрипт
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').validate();
});
поставил  <form id="ajax-contact-form" onsubmit="validate()">

а на submit_from что кидать?